# canvas.drawBitmap not working as expected

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

I am trying to add an image on top of another image. The one on the top is a blurred image. I am using the following code to try and achieve this.

```
    //First image as a background(full size)
    mCanvas.drawBitmap(canvasBackImage, 0, 0, null); //draws fine
    Rect rectangle = new Rect(0,0,200,200);

    //Second image on top blurred 200px x 200px rectangle
    mCanvas.drawBitmap(blurBuilder.blur(appContext, canvasBackImage, mX, mY), null, rectangle, null);
```

The image is drawn fine with the above code at coordinate 0,0 of the canvas however, if I modify the above code's line three to the following, it doesn't add the image at the 100,100 coordinate of the canvas.

```
    Rect rectangle = new Rect(100,100,200,200);
```

I also tried it with 50,50 coordnate and it works. So Changing it the following works too.

```
    Rect rectangle = new Rect(50,50,200,200);
```

I have no idea why this is not working as I expect it to. Am I doing something wrong?

My ultimate objective is to blur the image at the exact location that the user touched. So if user touched in the middle of the screen then that part of the image will be blurred out.

Comment: if you want only subset to be drawn, then use `Rect src`, now you pass `null` as `src`

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite understand that

Comment: Read the Canvas docs then

Answer (score 0):

I moved the above code in onDraw method and it seems to be working as expected now.

Before I had it in a different method which was being called manually on a button click.